# Improve SQL query performance - using python + Flask Application

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am running a SQL query using python in a Flask Application. The query joins 2 tables and performs aggregations.

```
Table1

id name val
0  A    10
1  B    20
2  C    10

Table2

id cat price
0  1   10
0  2   20
1  1   10
1  2   10
2  1   10
```

While the query runs fine, performance is an issue. It takes way too long to pull the data. The result includes ~5000 rows of data.

```
# mysql connection
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'user1'
pwd = 'pwd1'
host =  'xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com'
port = 3306
database = 'db_name'
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(user,pwd,host,database))

con = engine.connect()

%%timeit
query = '''
        SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.val, avg(t2.price) as avg_price
        FROM Table1 t1
        JOIN Table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
        GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, t1.val
        '''

df = pd.read_sql(query, con);

con.close()

21.7 s ± 2.65 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

How can I improve query performance and reduce Application load time? Including this query in the Application has resulted in poor performance.

Comment: First, try separating time taken to execute the query from the time fetching the 5000 said rows.

Comment: The SQL is hard to read.  (as seen by the confusion in forpas's answer).  A column named `id` is, by convention, the primary key of a table, hence unique and (usually) auto_increment.  Please change the name of t2.id to something else.

Comment: How many rows in `table1`?  The task does not seem to be something that needs to be done very frequently; is it?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is aggregate in the table `Table2` and then join the results to `Table1`:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.avg_price
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id, AVG(price) AS avg_price
  FROM Table2 
  GROUP BY id
) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```

Assuming that the column `id` of `Table2` is indexed, the subquery will return fast only 1 row per `id` and the join will also be faster that your current code which aggregates over the results of the join.

Comment: `id` _cannot_ be the PK for table2 since there are dups.

Comment: @RickJames correct. I edited.